# Firebase Cloud Functions running a python script - needs dependencies

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a website with React and Firebase that utilizes an algorithm I wrote in python. The database and authentication for the project are both handled by Firebase, so I would like to keep the cloud functions in that same ecosystem if possible.

Right now, I'm using the python-shell npm package to send and receive data from NodeJS to my python script.
I have local unit testing set up so I can test the https.onCall functions locally without needing to deploy and test from the client.
When I am testing locally, everything works perfectly.
However, when I push the functions to the cloud and trigger the function from the client, the logs in the Firebase console show that the python script is missing dependencies.

What is the best way to ensure that the script has all the dependencies available to it up on the server?

I have tried:
-Copying the actual dependency folders from my library/.../site-packages and putting them in the same directory under the /functions folder with the python script. This almost works. I just run into an issue with numpy: "No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'" is printed to the logs in Firebase.

I apologize if this is an obvious answer. I'm new to Python, and the solutions I've found online seem way to elaborate or involve hosting the python code in another ecosystem (like AWS or Heroku). I am especially hesitant to go to all that work because it runs fine locally. If I can just find a way to send the dependencies up with the script I'm good to go.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: how about using docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the logs in the Firebase console show that the python script is missing dependencies.

That's because the nodejs runtime targeted by the Firebase CLI doesn't have everything you need to run python programs.

If you need to run a function that's primarily written in python, you should not use the Firebase CLI and instead uses the Google Cloud tools to [target the python runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime), which should do everything you want.  Yes, it might be extra work for you to learn new tools, and you will not be able to use the Firebase CLI, but it will be the right way to run python in Cloud Functions.